# how to convert int value to char value in java

Tags: java

I've been working on my project to create a conversion between char value and int value by following MIX computer's characters(based on base 56). It turned out I'm find with a conversion from char to int value by using getNumbericVale() method, but I could not figure out reserve conversion.

This is my code below

```
        final char c1,c2,c3,c4,c5;

    c1 = 'I';
    c2 = 'F';
    c3 = 'E';
    c4 = 'B';
    c5 = 'A';

    int c1Cal = Character.getNumericValue('I') - Character.getNumericValue('A') + 1;
    int c2Cal = Character.getNumericValue('F') - Character.getNumericValue('A') + 1;
    int c3Cal = Character.getNumericValue('E') - Character.getNumericValue('A') + 1;
    int c4Cal = Character.getNumericValue('B') - Character.getNumericValue('A') + 1;
    int c5Cal = Character.getNumericValue('A') - Character.getNumericValue('A') + 1;

    //encoded

    int b1 = (int) (c5Cal*Math.pow(56, 0));
    int b2 = (int) (c4Cal*Math.pow(56, 1));
    int b3 = (int) (c3Cal*Math.pow(56, 2));
    int b4 = (int) (c2Cal*Math.pow(56, 3));
    int b5 = (int) (c1Cal*Math.pow(56, 4));

    //Decoded number to character






    System.out.println("Original: "+c1+c2+c3+c4+c5);
    System.out.println("Encoded: "+(b1+b2+b3+b4+b5));
    System.out.println("decoded: "+???);
```

The result has to be 'IFEBA' character again. The assignment sheet mentions you need to use remainder to extract the least digit and integer division to move all the remaining digits down one place.

Comment: What is the point of using `Character.getNumericValue()`? The following produces same result, and is much shorter: `int c1Cal = 'I' - 'A' + 1;`

Comment: You'll need to decode your `int` with the reverse of the process you used to encode it. **Hint**: Think about *logarithms*. Also, your message will overflow quickly (since a Java `int` is 32-bits, that's only 5.5 characters in base-56).

Answer (score 1):

Try to use something like this for all your `int`:

```
  int a = 4;
  char b = (char) a;
```